# unable to resolve reference issue: The dependency runtime.native.System.Data.SqlClient.sni >= 4.0.0

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2015, tfs, msbuild, nuget

getting the below error, building via TFS Builds. However i am able to build the solution manually in visual studio.

Have also tried to run the solution through MSBuild.exe. It works fine.
Please help me resolve this issue.

[image]

[image]

Thanks in advance
Prashanth

Comment: Please share the relevant parts of your `project.json` file (dependencies, runtimes) and what command is used in TFS to build the project / restore NuGet packages.

Comment: we have a service project, contracts and adaptor project. Service projects refers to contract and adapter. Contracts is throwing the above error.                      {
  "version": "1.0.0-*",

  "dependencies": {
    "NETStandard.Library": "1.6.0",
    "System.Data.SqlClient": "4.1.0",
    "System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters": "4.0.0-rc3-24212-01",
    "System.Xml.XmlSerializer": "4.0.11"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "netstandard1.6": {
      "imports": "dnxcore50"
    }
  }
}

Comment: have already installed new .net core sdk, using msbuild.exe "solution.sln" to build. Also, i am able to build the solution in visualstudio 2015

Comment: is there a runtimes section in that project.json? If so, you shouldn't need one for `netstandard` libraries. Also, try to update all dependencies (nested lib 1.6.1, 4.3.0 of everything else)

Comment: Have updated screenshot of references, guessing i have all latest references. Please take a look

Comment: again: is there a runtimes section in the project.json?

Comment: sorry there is no runtime section in project.json file. except   "runtimeOptions": {
    "configProperties": {
      "System.GC.Server": true
    }
  },

Comment: I had a similar problem where I was unable to add a package and the output from nuget package manager was this same error. The way I fixed it was to add the reference directly to the project file. I think the nuget package manager is calling nuget.exe under the hood and dotnet restore is being used by visual studio upon detection of changes. All that to say, it may be possible that TFS is not using dotnet restore. Maybe an older version of MSBuild?

Answer (score 0):

From the errors you posted above, it shows that the assemblies isn't resolved. That may because that the Nuget packages are not restored during the build. Because you're building Donet core project and the default xaml build template can't restore nuget packages of Donet core projects, you need to add a **batch** file to run `dotnet restore` command before MSBuild.

First, Create .bat file and enter: the path should be where the project.json file locates when you get down to build agent server.

```
dotnet restore %BUILD_SOURCESDIRECTORY%\...\ProjectFolder
```

Secondly, check in the bat file to TFS and select it in the **Pre-build script path**.
[image]

### Update:

Edit the `global.json` file under your the solution. Change the SDK version to 1.0.0-preview2-003131 in this file.

[image]

```
{
  "projects": [ "src", "test" ],
  "sdk": {
    "version": "1.0.0-preview2-003131"
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. But getting this error:                                          The imported project "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\1.0.3\Microsoft\VisualStudio\
v14.0\DotNet\Microsoft.DotNet.Props" was not found. Confirm that the path in the
 <Import> declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk.

Comment: Found dotnet.props in path                                                                              C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudiov14.0\DotNet\Microsoft.DotNet.Props

Comment: @prashanthkr08 On your build agent, you need to use visual studio and install .net core for VS 2015 like what you installed on your local machine. Makre sure the environment on your build agent server is same with your local machine. https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/core

Comment: installed it too. still getting the same error. i copied                     C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\DotNet      to      c:\program files\dotnet\sdk\1.0.3.

Comment: Why is it referring 1.0.3 when in project.json its referred to 1.0.0-preview2-003131. Please clarify, i am unable to proceed .Thanks in advance

Comment: @prashanthkr08 Sorry for the late response. You need to check the `global.json` file, also change the SDK version in it. Please see the update of my reply.

Comment: Yes, i am having the same version mentioned in global.json. Still getting the same error.